# How to install Fastai V1 in windows 11 and python 3.9?

Tags: python-3.x, windows-11, fast-ai

I have a problem with Fastai v1. I don't know why, but since I reinstalled windows, I can't manage to make it work.

How do I install fastai v1 with python 3.9 in windows 11?